Problemas a la hora de integrar Eureka Server y una Api Gateway
saludos.
Estoy implementando una app de spring boot usando una arquitectura de microservicios, está esa formada por los componentes que se muestran en la imagen de abajo.
Ahora, el problema está que cuando trato de ejecutar el API GATEWAY usando el EUREKA SERVER para que el enrutamiento sea dinámico, no funciona.
Acá les muestro la configuración del Eureka server.
spring:
 application:
   name: eureka-server

eureka:
 instance:
   hostname: localhost
 client:
   register-with-eureka: false
   fetch-registry: false
   serverUrl:
     defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/

server:
 port: 8761


Acá les muestro la configuración del API gateway:
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway

  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: pedidos-microservice
          uri: lb://PEDIDOS-MICROSERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/pedidos/**
        - id: products-microservice
          uri: lb://PRODUCTS-MICROSERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/products/**

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
    register-with-eureka: true

Y la configuración de un microservicio
spring:
  application:
    name: pedidos-microservice

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orders
    username: root
    password:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update

eureka:
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.uuid}
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka

server:
  port: 0

Cuando se ejecutan todos los microservicios, la lista de microservicios en EUREKA es la siguiente:

Entonces , no entiendo por qué no funciona el Gateway cuando hago una solicitud, ¿No debería consultar al eureka server para enrutar y balancear cada microservicio automáticamente?
Está es la respuesta en postman:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-07-19T22:13:01.375+00:00",
    "path": "/pedidos/crear",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "requestId": "5cedbf0f-2"
}

Resalto que cuando en la configuración del Gateway pongo las URIs de manera estáticas si funciona, es decir, de la siguiente manera:

        - id: products-microservice
          uri: 'http://localhost:50695'
          predicates:
            - Path=/products/**

Sera que me falta algo en alguna parte? Cada clase principal de cada microservicio esta anotada con las anotaciones pertinentes para el correcto funcionamiento (anotaciones para habilitar los discovery client)
El error que se muestra en el registro de la API-GATEWAY es el siguiente:

